# How to test for a None value in Lua?

Tags: lua, null, nonetype

I'm currently developping a DOTA2 mod, using a Lua API.
I found that default `null` value in lua was `nil`.

After programming a bit, I am getting this error:

`Script Runtime Error: ...\scripts\vscripts\addon_game_mode.lua:71: Can't call CBaseEntity:GetHealth on an object of type [none]`

I tried to test if the value was equal to `none`, but `none` doesn't seems to exists in Lua...

I read online that was maybe due to the fact that DOTA is programmed in C++ or something, but i can't find a way to fix that error.

Do you have any idea to fix my problem ? Is there maybe a way to test if the class is none ?
Here is the source code :

```lua
creature = nil

function CustomGameMode:makeSpawn()
    -- Make next ennemy spawn  (creature ~=none makes the problem)
    if (HeroList:GetHeroCount() == 0 or creature ~= nil or creature ~= none) then
        print("Not spawned or not killed yet")
        return 5
    end

    print( "Spawning units..." )
    -- If the unit doesn't exists, spawn it
    local spawnLocation = Entities:FindByName( nil, "test_spawning" )
    creature = CreateUnitByName( "npc_dota_neutral_alpha_wolf" , spawnLocation:GetAbsOrigin(),
    true, nil, nil, DOTA_TEAM_NEUTRALS )
    -- when the unit dies, creature have a "none" value
    return 30 -- This function calls itself every 30 seconds
end
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `HeroList:GetHeroCount() == 0 or creature ~= nil or creature ~= none`  Why `~=`?

Comment: Doesn't that ~=  means different ? (like != in other languages)

Comment: Probably you need `and` instead of `or`.